# Open IE page through client side

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

How can I open a IE page in client side ?

**Example:**
We use FireFox as default browser for our web system. My users in a specific moment has to print a page. How can I print a page through FireFox ?

**Details:**
To access the printer we need `ActiveX`, but FireFox doesn't accept `ActiveX`. I tried access the printer through `Dll` but works just localhost, because this is server side, so if I deploy my application in my server, the printer won't work in client side. My third try, was open the `IE` via code-behind, but this is also server side, just works in localhost.

I just need open a specific page in IE (because of activex), when I'm using FireFox, but in client side.

How can I do that ?

Comment: Why not just let them print the page using Firefox? Open a window with the content, perhaps with a print-specific stylesheet, and issue a `window.print();` on it. Firefox will handle the rest.

Comment: [window.print();](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.print)

Comment: But `window.print()` will print in the default printer, I need print in a specific one.

Comment: Other browsers do not offer this sort of functionality, sorry. Try writing the instructions on the webpage itself for non-IE users.

Comment: window.print() should automatically provide a dialog? You mean this dialog doesn't show the right printer? Does your system have something weird in place to prevent users from selecting a printer.

Comment: But look, I open a page to my user, if I click to print, I will print the page but in different formats, words, etc. So, `window.print()` its not appropriate, because this will print the page the same way that are showed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use client-side code to open IE from Firefox without installing a plug-in or protocol handler or similar. That's a complex route to go down and, of course, requires that your users install something specific.

Instead, I'd suggest letting them print the page using Firefox. Open a window with the content, perhaps with a print-specific stylesheet, and issue a `window.print();` on it. Firefox will handle the rest.

Comment: But `window.print()` will print in the default printer, I need print in a specific one.

Comment: @Lucas_Santos: No, it won't. `window.print` will open a dialog box (or similar) which allows the user to select the printer to use.

Comment: But look, I open a page to my user, if I click to print, I will print the page but in different formats, words, etc. So, `window.print()` its not appropriate, because this will print the page the same way that are showed.

Comment: @Lucas_Santos: Read the answer again. My suggestion was to open a window with the content you want to print, and (optionally) to use a print style sheet (`@media print { ... }`). You can control what gets printed, and how it looks. Search for "using a print style sheet" for more.

Answer (score 0):

Browsers do not provide web pages with the means to run arbitrary software, so you cannot.

Answer (score 0):

If you call in javascript `window.print();` the standard print dialog will get opened. So no need for any dll's or activex.

Comment: But `window.print()` will print in the default printer, I need print in a specific one.

Comment: @Lucas_Santos How can you know what printer a client has? You can't know that for sure.

Comment: @SynerCoder It might be an in-house application.

Comment: But look, I open a page to my user, if I click to print, I will print the page but in different formats, words, etc. So, `window.print()` its not appropriate, because this will print the page the same way that are showed.